# Configure ip kubespray: "msg": "IPv4: '['.....']' and IPv6: '['f....']' do not contain '....'"

Tags: kubernetes

I want to install Kubernetes on Oracle Cloud VMs using Kubespray. I tried these steps:

```
apt install python3-pip

git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray
cd kubespray
git checkout master #if you want to change version

sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
cp -rfp inventory/sample inventory/mycluster

declare -a IPS=(192.168.1.24 192.168.1.25 192.168.1.26)
CONFIG_FILE=inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml python3 contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py ${IPS[@]}
    
vi inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml

ansible-playbook -i inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml  --become --become-user=root cluster.yml
```

Into Oracle cloud every VM have a private IP for example 10.0.0.x and public 141.147.3.x. I get this error during Kubespray execution:

```
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {

    "assertion": "(ip in ansible_all_ipv4_addresses) or (ip in ansible_all_ipv6_addresses)",

    "changed": false,

    "evaluated_to": false,

    "msg": "IPv4: '['10.0.0.x']' and IPv6: '['........']' do not contain '141.147.3.x'"
}
```

Into cluster file I have this configuration:

```
all:
  hosts:
    node1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.24
      ip: 192.168.1.24
      access_ip: 192.168.1.24
    node2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.25
      ip: 192.168.1.25
      access_ip: 192.168.1.25
    node3:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.26
      ip: 192.168.1.26
      access_ip: 192.168.1.26
  children:
    kube_control_plane:
      hosts:
        node1:
    kube_node:
      hosts:
        node2:
        node3:
    etcd:
      hosts:
        node1:
        node2:
        node3:
    k8s_cluster:
      children:
        kube_control_plane:
        kube_node:
    calico_rr:
      hosts: {}
```

- These are just example IPs

Do you know how I can solve this issue?